# Не выводятся данные Django

Tags: django, nginx

Салют всем. У меня на сервере (debian+nginx порт80) есть будущий интернет-магазин на Django (oscar).
Беру я архив всей папки сайта, копирую на свой ноут (где тоже debian+nginx порт80), копирую БД и запускаю сайт через makefile.

И сайт заупускается, на главной странице всё 1в1, захожу в админки там тоже самое всё 1в1, есть все товары. НО если на сайте в ноуте(локально) перехожу в какую-то категорию - там 0 товаров! А на сервере всё работает - http://aleol.ru/catalogue/category/bytovaia-khimiia_1/

Так же если я локально в админке нахожу товар, нажимаю "посмотреть на сайте" - страница самого товара открывается.

Просьба поделится соображениями по возможной причине такого различия и как ее исправить.

Comment: 607 результатов - показаны с 1 по 20 или это такая разновидность SEO?

Comment: скорее всего причина в настройка самого nginx

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov На сервере да 607. А на ноутбуке локально - 0. Могу скрин сделать. (до сео на этом сайте ещё далеко)

Comment: @Insider конфигурационные файлы доменов .conf и там и там одинаковые почти, кроме путей. Имеете ввиду фаил nginx.conf ?

Comment: @МихаилСоснин да, извиняюсь что не уточнил, но именно его я и имею ввиду )

Comment: @Insider скопировал содержимое этого файла с сервера и перезапустил nginx - ничего не изменилось. Там почти одинаковые настройки были.

Comment: @МихаилСоснин хм, вы написано, ли что если в админки находите товар, то все работает, ссылка на товар такая же как и на сервере?

Comment: @Insider Да, ссылка такая же (только домен другой) и открывается такая же страница. И в категориях такие же адреса, только 0 товаров выводит. Тоже на оптовой странице http://aleol.ru/catalogue/bulk/ везде товаров не найдено (локально), а на сервере - ок

Comment: в админке товары все есть, всё так же, и все страницы самих товаров открываются так же (и на сервере и локально). А содержимое категорий - пусто.